# Select2 Select in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, jquery-select2

I've already checked the other threads, covering this problem, but none of this solutions work for me.

I'm using jquery 1.11.2, select2-4.0.0-beta.3 and bootstrap-3.3.1

My modal looks like following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addProductModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Product</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            {!! BootForm::openHorizontal(2,10)->action('/recipes/'.$recipe->id.'/product')->post() !!}

              {!! BootForm::select('Produkte: ','product_list[]' , $products)->id('products') !!}
              {!! BootForm::submit('Erstellen') !!}

              {!! BootForm::token() !!}
            {!! BootForm::close() !!}

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And I want to call `$('#products').select2();`
The plugin works fine in other places. But it's screwed up in a modal:

[image: http://imgur.com/rzcTVTD]

Update: (Not) Working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Strernd/o0d3vtek/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The issue you're having is that, when Select2 is binded to the select, the generated span is something like:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 100px;">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="select2-products-results" aria-labelledby="select2-products-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-products-container">Mein Produkt</span>
            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

You'll notice the hardcoded `width: 100px` that forces the text to be "splitted". You might be thinking "why the hell?!" and the response most certainly is: you're using a beta version.

You can solve this issue by:

1. Forcing `width: 100%` with the following CSS code:

   ```
   .select2-container {
       width: 100% !important;
       padding: 0;
   }
   ```

   Take a look at [**this working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/o0d3vtek/2/) (I added some `col-xs` classes to your label and another div). Beware that this solution works as long as you have enough width for your text. If the width is smaller than the text you'll have the same issue and you'll need to tweak the CSS to add `overflow: auto;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;`
2. Use the latest stable version 3.5.2, which works correctly as [**this jsfiddle shows**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/o0d3vtek/3/).

Comment: Solutions 2 seems good. It was dumb to use the beta version.
But now I have this issue http://i.imgur.com/wAHIpKD.png

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap you'll need two CSS files. The common `select2.css` and aditionally `select2-bootstrap.min.css` (see the fiddle resources). For a more "Bootstrap-like" effect, take a look at this page: https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/

Comment: I used solution #1 because I had to use the beta version and it's working. Still, I'm wondering why is that 100px style hardcoded... Thank you!

Comment: I'm having this problem with version select2 4.0.0. The problem only occurs when the `<select>` is within a Foundation reveal modal; if it is anywhere else on the page select2 works as expected. I noticed `width: 100px` appears in the rendered HTML (when inside of modal), but `100px` exists nowhere in the source code. It seems to be generated dynamically, and in conflict with inside a modal (bootstrap *and* foundation???). Still, solution #1 works in this case as well. =\

Comment: Nice solution from GitHub by kevin-brown.

Override in your CSS
.select2-dropdown {
  z-index: 9001;
}

Comment: We are having the same issue with the 3.5.2 version but your solution worked like a charm for us too.

Answer (score 8):

```
span.select2-container {
    z-index:10050;
}
```

does not work when you have `select2` outside of the modal.

`EDIT`

I found this would be a better solution when using `select2` in Bootstrap Modal and outside them.

```
.select2-container--open{
        z-index:9999999         
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's perfect if you'r using one modal over another modal. Change only select2-container z-index will end up in a mess on a robust structure.

Comment: Perfect solution...@dannyzar

Answer (score 7):

You can use this [link](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1645) when you want to use `select2` in modal:

```
$('#my-select').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#my-modal')
});
```

Answer (score 5):

What I did was to add this code just above the page

```
    span.select2-container {
    z-index:10050;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this works, don't just 'dump code'

Comment: z-index is enough explanation